# Don't work subtraction/multiplication/division but work addition

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator

***Hello!***
In my calculator program don't work subtraction/multiplication/division methods but work addition method.

Addition method:

```
-(IBAction) clickPlus
{
    [self processOp: '+'];
}
```

Subtraction method:

```
-(IBAction) clickMinus
{
    [self processOp: '-'];
}
```

Process method:

```
-(void) processOp: (char) theOp
{
    NSString *opStr;

    op = theOp;

    switch (theOp) {
        case '+':
            opStr = @" + ";
            break;
        case '-':
            opStr = @" – ";
            break;
        case '*':
            opStr = @" * ";
            break;
        case '/':
            opStr = @" ÷ ";
            break;
    }

    [self storeFracPart];
    firstOperand = NO;
    isNumerator = YES;

    [displayString appendString: opStr];
    display.text = displayString;
}
```

In that method 'op' variable is used: "**clickEquals**"

```
-(IBAction) clickEquals
{
    if ( firstOperand == NO )
    {
        [self storeFracPart];
        [myCalculator performOperation: op];

        [displayString appendString: @" = "];
        [displayString appendString: [myCalculator.accumulator
                                      convertToString]];
        display.text = displayString;

        currentNumber = 0;
        isNumerator = YES;
        firstOperand = YES;
        [displayString setString: @""];
    }
}
```

Why do you think that 'op' collect garbage?

If you need more code just let me know.

Comment: Assuming that `op` is an instance variable or a property, it looks like it's going to get garbage value, because you copy `opStr` into it before making any assignments. If you end up using `op` later on, the results will be random.

Comment: Have you put breakpoints or `NSLog` statements in your various `clickMinus`, `clickMultiply`, and `clickDivide` (or whatever they're called) methods to make sure they're hooked up correctly in interface builder?

Comment: And when you say it doesn't work, does it do nothing, or does it do something, but just the wrong thing? If the latter, what is it doing? Precisely what behavior are you seeing and what behavior do you want to see?

Comment: Run it in the debugger.  Put a breakpoint on the first line of `processOp:` and single step through it.

Comment: I updated my question. Check it out pls.

Answer (score 0):

What is `op` in `clickEquals`? Is it supposed to be a class ivar? If so `processOp` is wrong as it's using a local variable called `op` and is therefore never assigning the ivar.

You should learn to debug this kind of problems yourself. It's not too hard. If you step through the code execution line by line in the debugger and watch what changes when you should be able to find this sort of problems.